# Segmentation fault with nodes

Tags: c++, list, unix, nodes

On this code I keep running into a segmentation fault when I try to insert into the front of the linked list. I assume it has to do with the head not being changed over properly. In this program baskets are nodes. The debugger I used pointed to the last line in the function as the issue but I am not exactly sure where it originates.

```
include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "BasketList.h"

using namespace std;

Basket::Basket(int _datum, Basket * _next):
   egg_num(_datum), nextBasket(_next)
{}


int Basket::getEggs() const
{
   return egg_num;
}


Basket const* Basket::getNextBasket() const
{
   return nextBasket;
}


BasketList::BasketList() :
head (NULL)
{}

void BasketList::insertBasket(int eggs)
{
   Basket *currPtr = head;
   Basket *prevPtr = NULL;
   Basket *newBasketPtr;

   if(eggs  < head->egg_num)
   {
   currPtr->nextBasket = head;
   head = currPtr;
   }


   while(currPtr != NULL && eggs > currPtr->egg_num)
   {
      prevPtr = currPtr;
      currPtr = currPtr->nextBasket;
   }

   newBasketPtr = new Basket(eggs, currPtr);
   prevPtr->nextBasket = newBasketPtr;

}
```

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would save us a lot of tedious work.

Comment: prevPtr is almost certainly NULL on your first insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for `head` being `NULL` before you use it.

Your constructor sets `head` to `NULL`, then when you call `insertBasket` the first thing it does is dereference the pointer `head`.

I think you can get rid of the first if statement (and its contents) in your `insertBasket` altogether - the loop should do what you want. You will just need to then check at the end if `prevPtr` is NULL, if so, set `head` to `newBasketPtr`

Comment: So inside of the insertBasket function I need to first check if head is null before i execute the loop?

Comment: You already set currPtr to head, then check whether currPtr is NULL, so you don't need a second check. The problem is in your if test condition, not the loop condition.

Comment: If that original if statement is unnecessary and I remove it then where is the problem now at? Since you said the problem was in the first if condition. Also if currPtr does equate to NULL does it then need to be set equal to newBasketPtr?

Comment: If currPtr is NULL, then you won't enter the loop, leaving you with a condition at the end that prevPtr is NULL. This will occur if either head is NULL, or if the first item is greater than or equal to the passed in eggs value. If that is the case (prevPtr being NULL), you want to set head to newBasketPtr instead of setting prevPtr->nextBasket to newBasketPtr.